# How do these two patterns differ, with regards to API design?

Tags: api, rest

I am learning API design, and based on the blog I am reading

`GET http://www.nowhere.com/images/getImage?imageId=123`

is an antipattern, and should be avoided.

while the blog does not mention this, I guess the preferred method would be

`GET http://www.nowhere.com/images/123`

How is the second method the preferred method? what exactly is wrong/limitation with the first method?

Answer (score 1):

> How is the second method the preferred method? what exactly is wrong/limitation with the first method?

Both spellings, as far as REST is concerned, are *fine*; REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

The first variation is more convenient when you are trying to integrate with HTML forms.  The second variation is more convenient when you want to use relative references.

---

There is a bias among designers against the first spelling, because it has the appearance of reflecting a misunderstanding of how resource models work in HTTP.

```
GET /images/123
```

Is closely analogous to this psuedo code

```
resouce("/images/123").get()
```

Similarly

```
GET /images/getImage?imageId=123
```

is analogous to

```
resource("/images/getImage?imageId=123").get()
```

Contrast this with:

```
resource("/images").getImage(imageId=123)
```

---

Expressed another way: the resource identifier is the identifier of the document that you are fetching, which you might think of as the name of the document.

So the argument is about whether "getImage" (a verb phrase) makes a good name for a document (noun), in much the same way that you might get push back in a code review were you to propose "getImage" as a variable name that holds a reference to a data structure.

Much like variable names in code, the machines *don't care*, either spelling will work just fine.  But we see resource identifiers (in browser location controls, browser histories, bookmark lists, access logs, etc) a lot more frequently than we do variable names, so it is more important that they are easy for humans to work with.